# Printing a calendar via Python. Code is not working =/

Tags: python, subprocess, pygtk, lpr

I am making a small program in Python (PyGTK) that prints out a calendar (Gregorian) for a year the user inputs.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk, gtk, subprocess
pygtk.require("2.0")

class Base:
    def printing(self, widget):
        text = self.textbox.get_text()
        printingit = "cal -y %s | lpr" % (text)
        process = subprocess.Popen(printingit.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = process.communicate()[0]   

    def __init__(self):
            self.win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
            self.win.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
            self.win.set_size_request(350, 200)
        self.win.set_resizable(False)
        self.win.set_title("Calendar")
        self.win.connect('destroy',lambda w: gtk.main_quit())

        self.textbox = gtk.Entry()
        self.textbox.set_size_request(70, 30)

        self.lable = gtk.Label("Year:")

        self.button = gtk.Button("Print")
        self.button.set_size_request(60, 45)
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.printing)

        box = gtk.Fixed()
        box.put(self.lable, 160, 25)
        box.put(self.textbox, 140, 40)
        box.put(self.button, 145, 100)

        self.win.add(box)
        self.win.show_all()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = Base()
    base.main()
```

It's not working when actually printing the command `cal -y %s | lpr % (text)`. I have made it so it replaces the textbox's text with the final command it should get and it changes to what I want it to be `cal -y 2015 | lpr`. I tried just putting that into terminal and it worked as usual, it's confusing me a lot!

I ran the program in terminal and this is the message I recieve when it tries to print:

```
Usage: cal [general options] [-hjy] [[month] year]
   cal [general options] [-hj] [-m month] [year]
   ncal [general options] [-bhJjpwySM] [-s country_code] [[month] year]
   ncal [general options] [-bhJeoSM] [year]
General options: [-NC3] [-A months] [-B months]
For debug the highlighting: [-H yyyy-mm-dd] [-d yyyy-mm]
```

If anyone understands why this is happening I would be extremely grateful! Thank you in advance =D

- Harry

Comment: What flavour of "not working"? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: What I meant by not working was it wasn't printing (like onto paper) from my default printer. All the errors I received were what I posted and the only output was a frozen program and the error in my terminal. In the text field I input 2015 and got the output I posted.

Comment: Why are you wrapping your procedural code in a useless class? Is this some sort of infection by Java?

Comment: @ErikAllik I am using a class to call the main function without an error. This is simply because I don't know another way of doing this =D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use shell syntax (pipe) in your command, you need to pass the command as as string to the [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) constructor, not as list. And you must use `shell=True`:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(printingit, shell=True)
```

Without that, the executed command would be the same as:

`cal '-y' 'text' '|' 'lpr'`

But as you're getting part of the input from a text field, you shouldn't directly pass it tho a shell.

Alternatively, you can create the pipe yourself:

```
lpr = subprocess.Popen('lpr', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process = subprocess.Popen(['cal', '-y', text], stdout=lpr.stdin)
output = lpr.communicate()
process.wait()
```

By the way, instead of using subprocess to invoke `cal` you could use the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) module. `cal -y 2012` does the same as `calendar.calendar(2014)`, so you could replace your code with:

```
cal = calendar.calendar(int(text))
process = subprocess.Popen(['lpr'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate(cal)   # cal.encode(locale.getpreferredencoding(False)) for python3
```